# VBA Code to Loop Copying Sheet Containing Graph by Changing Plot Series (One column over) for Each Plot

Tags: excel, vba, plot, automation

For my work I have an excel template from a state department containing a unique plot that I need to add my data to. The issue is that I need to create over 100 plots of this. I currently have a massive table with different x and y variables that need to go on each. I've been trying to come up with a VBA code that automates making a copy of the current sheet (which I know how to do) and then each copy contains the data one column over until there are none left.

The code I currently have is this.

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Set Ws = Worksheets("HOUSES")

Ws.Copy After:=Sheets("HOUSES")

ActiveSheet.Name = "HOUSES 2"
srs.Values = "=DATA!$C$2:$C$4"
srs.Name = "=""Change Series Name"""

Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
srs.Values = "=DATA!$C$2:$C$4"
srs.Name = "=""New Series"""
'Set the values for the X axis when using XY Scatter
srs.XValues = "=DATA!$D$2:$D$4"
End Sub
```

I know there are some steps missing but if anyone could guide me on the right track that would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code below will create a new line graph for each column of data as a new chartsheet and label the sheet with the column header.  It assumes that you start the code with the data sheet selected (`Activesheet`), but you can easily change this.

```
Sub GenCharts()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim CH As chart
    Dim xlCell As Range
        Set WS = ActiveSheet
        Set xlCell = WS.Range("B1")
        Do Until xlCell = ""
            Set CH = WS.Parent.Charts.Add
            With CH
                .SetSourceData Source:=WS.Range(WS.Name & "!$A$1:$A$10" & "," & xlCell.Address & ":" & xlCell.Offset(9, 0).Address)
                .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:=xlCell & "_Chart"
                .ChartType = xlLineMarkersStacked
            End With
            Set CH = Nothing
            Set xlCell = xlCell.Offset(0, 1)
        Loop
        Set xlCell = Nothing
        Set WS = Nothing
End Sub
```